# How to use GCP API-Gateway for App Engine microservices?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, microservices, google-cloud-api-gateway

I have multiple services deploy on App Engine default environment. Now I want to create a API-Gateway to make the calling of the services easier to use in Frontend. Also I can then use the security provided by the GCP API-Gateway.

App Engine:
Service 1
Service 2
Service 3

API-Gateway
API-Gateway 1 --> containing all the endpoints for all services

The GCP docs for API-Gateway uses a single config file for an api and gateway. But when you have 20 services and each service has 10 endpoints you would have an huge config file

Questions:

- Is API-Gateway the best way to use for App Engine microservices ?
- Should something like dispatch.yaml routing be used for this case ?
- What are best use cases to handle this problem in GCP ?

Comment: It's the service for that. The dispatch could be useless if you wrap correctly the API endpoint and the backend invocation. However, you have to describe the whole endpoints in a APISpec doc to deploy correctly the endpoint.

Comment: So I will have a huge config for all services with all endpoints for each service ?

Comment: ..... yes, that's why, I prefer to mention it. If you can, automatise this generation.